# Trouble with negative float values in Python Lists

Tags: python, list, floating-point

So i'm trying to work with floats as elements in Python lists but I keep getting this error. I tried making each value a string and then converting it to a float when calling the array to print but that doesn't seem to work either

```
P1 = [45.100000, ‐65.400000]
print(P1[0])
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

*Attempt #2*

```
P1 = ["45.100000", "‐65.400000"]
print(float(P1[1]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '‐65.400000'
```

I have a feeling the issues have to do with the negative value in front of the 2nd elements (@ index 1)

Comment: I jut copied your code into a python interpreter and it's not working either. I replaced the negative symbol with the one off my keyboard ( - ) and it worked. Are you using the correct negative symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and ran it, and all I had to do was replace the "-" Seems like you were using a bad character. Try this;

```
P1 = [45.100000, -65.400000]
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to fix the problem -_-

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with the hyphen you are using. If you cut and paste the hyphen in your list `p1`, and check the unicode, it gives:

```
>>> ord('‐')
8208
```

Whereas the proper negative or subtraction sign should be:

```
>>> ord('-')
45
```

Depending on how you got that list, you either have to figure out why that character got included, or re-type it with the proper `Hyphen-Minus`

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `-` is not a minus sign but a hyphen character:

```
>>> "‐65.400000".encode('utf-8') # copy from your example
b'\xe2\x80\x9065.400000'

>>> "-65.400000".encode('utf-8') # Replace with my minus
b'-65.400000'
```

`\xe2\x80\x90` is a hyphen character, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode): your hyphen is `U+2010` and the hyphen-minus is `U+002D`